# unstable quad with naza m lite

Tags: quadcopter

I almost finished my first quad and first time it just flipped(the back over the front 360 degrees)...the motors and  props are installed correctly..i triple checked but i'm still a  noob in this...my quad specs are q330 frame with naza m lite (with gps),hobbywing 30a esc,rs 2205 motors ,flysky fs i6 with ia6b,3s battery ... maybe someone can help with my problem...i don't want to loose to many props or even worse...thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possibilities for the flip of quadrotor.

1. It can be because of incorrect prop directions (in X or + configuration, the diagonally opposite props must have same rotational direction and adjacent props must have opposite rotational direction; This is all about compensation of angular momentum).
2. It can be because of a faulty ESC or improperly tuned ESC. There are several ways to tune ESCs properly. (Like this: https://librepilot.atlassian.net/wiki/display/LPDOC/ESC+Calibration )
3. It can be an issue of PID tuning. (http://myfirstdrone.com/tutorials/how-to-tune-a-quadcopter/ https://oscarliang.com/quadcopter-pid-explained-tuning/ )
4. IMU may not be calibrated properly and the EKF estimates may be wrong. (https://fpv-flightclub.com/quadcopter-flips-takeoff/ Accelerometer and Gyro orientation along with Compass need to be properly set up)
5. (Rare) GPS functionality might be malfunctioning ending that up with GPS locks for inaccurate location estimates.

BTW, there are many forums that address this issue and simple Google search is ending up with results like:

https://oscarliang.com/quadcopter-flies-unstable-flips-troubleshoot/

http://diydrones.com/forum/topics/quadcopter-flips-on-liftoff

https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?2284434-My-x-quadcopter-flips-on-takeoff

Please consider mentioning what you have tried and what hasn't worked (otherwise this question is 'too broad' with many Google results popping up for same).